# Email sign in with laravel using homestead as server

Tags: laravel, google-signin, homestead

I want to do sign in with google in Laravel project. But it is not working properly . I do alot of things but it can't help me. Now i am testing it with homestead.

**Here is routes**

`Route::get('login/google', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToGoogle')->name('login.google');`
`Route::get('login/google/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleGoogleCallback');`

**Here is login controller**

```
public function redirectToGoogle()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}
public function handleGoogleCallback()
{
    $google_user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    $user = User::where('email', $google_user->getEmail())->first();

    if($user){
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('/');
    }else{
        $newUser = User::create([
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'user_type' => UserTypes::SystemUser,
        ]);

        Auth::login($newUser);
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**I redirect on sign in with google using this button**

`<a href="{{ route('login.google') }}" class="login-href"><i class="fab fa-google login-icon">Continue with google</i>`

[image: Here is google setting]

[I follow this link](https://appdividend.com/2018/04/11/laravel-google-login-tutorial/)

When i click on Continue with google , get this error
[image: Here is error]

Comment: try domain name to change the local?

Comment: but i am using homestead, there i defined gws.test